# How Can i Use C language in .Net (C IDE)

Tags: .net, c

Is it possible to use C code in .NET?

Comment: Why do you want to know?  (This question looks like it may not ask what you really want to know.)

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.

If you write a com DLL in C, you can use it in .NET using PInvoke and interop.

See [Interoperating with Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k.aspx) on MSDN.

Alternatively, use [managed C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C++)/[C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI).